# ArcGIS REST API: MapServer/export returns "The requested layer (layerId: export) was not found."

Tags: arcgis

I have created a Tiled Map and it works great when opened in ArcGIS online.

I'm in C++ using CURL to send direct REST request to the ArcGIS servers, and it works ok for the most part.

But when I try to export this Tiled Map via `MapServer/export` REST end point, i'm getting `"The requested layer (layerId: export) was not found."`

If I use the same export on other maps, but works ok. What could be wrong?